# web3 update monitoring

Tags: metamask, events, web3-providers

Inside a DAPP, I have been using

```
web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update',...
```

to monitoring Metamask activity.

But in the new metamask-mobile such method does not exists.

There is a better way to listed for updates?

`setTimeout` seems a poor solution.

Tanks

Comment: What kind of events do you need to capture? “Metamask activity” sounds too generic.

Comment: Currently, `update` is launched for example when the user changes the current network, or when a transactions is completed.

Comment: A little self serving, but my colleague did write a guide on monitoring Web3 transactions: https://www.moesif.com/blog/blockchain/ethereum/Tutorial-for-building-Ethereum-Dapp-with-Integrated-Error-Monitoring/#